# OverflowException when getting out parameters from a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a store procedure. From this I want output value but there is
 showing the following error:

> System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for an Int32.

My Store Procedure

```
ALTER proc dbo.[RECnoofDue]        
@acno varchar(100),
@NoofDue numeric(18,2) output        
as 
Begin
select @NoofDue=isnull(SUM(Avgr),0) from (
select NoOfDue, LHEMI, TotalEMIDue, sunday, Avgr from 
(SELECT     COUNT(LHID) AS NoOfDue, LHEMI, SUM(LHEMI) AS TotalEMIDue, 
SUM((Case when LHSundryBalance is null then 0 else LHSundryBalance end)) AS sunday,
((SUM(LHEMI)-SUM((Case when LHSundryBalance is null then 0 else LHSundryBalance end))) / LHEMI) AS Avgr
FROM dbo.TblLoanHistory WHERE (LHAcNo = @acno) AND 
(LHEMIPaid = 0 OR LHEMIPaid IS NULL)AND (LHFileStatus IS NULL) GROUP BY LHSundryBalance, LHEMI,LHFileStatus ) x
union
(SELECT     COUNT(LHID) AS NoOfDue, LHEMI, SUM(LHTotalOverDue) AS TotalEMIDue, 
SUM((Case when LHSundryBalance is null then 0 else LHSundryBalance end)) AS sunday,
((SUM(LHTotalOverDue)-SUM((Case when LHSundryBalance is null then 0 else LHSundryBalance end))) / LHEMI) AS Avgr
FROM dbo.TblLoanHistory WHERE (LHAcNo = @acno) AND (LHEMIPaid = 0 OR LHEMIPaid IS NULL) AND 
(LHFileStatus = 'BK')GROUP BY LHSundryBalance, LHEMI)) bb

end
```

My ASP.NET C# Code

```
private double NOofDueCount()
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OptimaWebCustomerQueryCon"].ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.RECnoofDue", conn))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@acno", SqlDbType.Int);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoofDue", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            cmd.Parameters["@acno"].Value = hfLoanAcNo.Value;
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (dr.Read())
                {
                    return Convert.ToDouble(cmd.Parameters["@NoofDue"].Value);
                    //int contractID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@NoofDue"].Value);
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is `hfLoanAcNo` declared as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a `decimal` (`SqlDbType.Decimal`) instead of an `int`, and make sure your `@acno` is a `string`, (`SqlDbType.NVarChar`)

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@acno", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoofDue", SqlDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

...

return Convert.ToDecimal(cmd.Parameters["@NoofDue"].Value);
```

Or possibly a `double` (`SqlDbType.Float`), which might have been the original intent since your method returns a `double`:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@acno", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@NoofDue", SqlDbType.Float).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

...

double NoofDue = Convert.ToDouble(cmd.Parameters["@NoofDue"].Value);
```

Comment: @NurMuhammad You'll also have to make sure `@acno` has the correct parameter type. See my updated answer.

Comment: I am extremely sorry for my falt. I have change  cmd.Parameters.Add("@acno", SqlDbType.Int) To cmd.Parameters.Add("@acno", SqlDbType.NVarChar); and my result is found but there is problem that all result is shows as 0. Is there any problem with data type?

Comment: Are you sure that your stored procedure returns a value? And you can probably eliminate the check `if (dr.Read())`.